# Validation on onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to do validation onkeyup and onsubmit.
I have field called CVV which accepts 3 or 4 digits numbers, so i'm using '`^(d){3,4}$`'.
This pattern works properly when i did in onsubmit function, but in onkeyup function i get always `false` even i enter 3 digits number.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="callonkeyup(this,'First Name','^(d){3,4}$')" value="First Name">

    function callonkeyup(tag,defaultValue,pattern){
        var isValidate = validate(pattern,trim(tag.value),defaultValue);
        console.log("==isValidate=="+isValidate+"==tag.value=="+tag.value+"===pattern==="+pattern);

    }

    function validate(pattern,value,defaultVal){
        var returnValue = false;
        if(value && value != defaultVal){
            while(pattern.indexOf('\\\\') != -1) {
                pattern = pattern.replace('\\\\', "\\");
            }
            var testPattern = new RegExp(pattern,"");
            if (testPattern.test(value)){
                returnValue = true;
            }else{ 
                returnValue = false;
            }
        } 
        return returnValue; 
    }

    function trim(value){
        return value.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    }
```

Comment: make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: the d in your pattern should be \d to represent numeric values, or it will just represent the character d.

Comment: @becquerel: i tried with \d, it is not working

Comment: Yes sorry, try to escape it, as @gurpreet-singh says in his answer. I missed that one - I will jsfiddle it next time :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `\` in front of the `d`, without it the `d` is represented as the character d and not a numeric value. Here's the expression you should use `^\d{3,4}$`.

**EDIT**

The first part was on track, but I missed that you were passing the pattern as a string to another function. If you were to run `new RegExp('^\d{3,4}$', "")` it would work, but because it was being passed through a function, the `\` character was being removed. In order to pass a string with a backslash in it, you need to escape the slash with another back slash like so `\\`. This means your new expression should be `^\\d{3,4}$`.

When developing regular expression I usually use something like http://regexpal.com/ to help test them. Keep in mind that for this one you would have to check the `^$ match at line breaks (m)` box for it to match multiple tests on multiple lines

Comment: the pattern fails in onkeyup event but not in onclick event and i tried with '^\d{3,4}$'.

Comment: @user2677473 your jsfiddle wasn't working because of the placement in the doc `onload` vs `in head`. Your onkeyup wasn't working because it was expecting more parameters. I'll update my answer to explain why in fact you need two `\` for this to work

Answer (score 1):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GxDnW/)

You need to escape back slash (`\`) so your regular expression should be `^\\d{3,4}$` instead `^(d){3,4}$`

Comment: thank you very much it is working, but i have one doubt how come it works in onclick event

Comment: Not sure, you need to give me an example for that.